# Running games in DirectX 6

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

I've just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8UIZzUU4Ns) where I saw Counter Strike: Global Offensive is running in Direct X 6. This makes **HUGE** difference on FPS and also lower the graphics quality so much. This makes me wonders and want to try it. How does one run CS:GO (or any Source Engine based game) on bare minimum Direct X 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable DirectX 6 mode with the command line "-dxlevel 60".

[image: right click on game -> "properties"]
[image: "set launch options..."]
[image: launch options: "-dxlevel 60"]

Comment: Has anyone tried running CS:GO in DirectX 6?

Comment: Question tho... Why is it `60` and not `6`?

Comment: Because versions of directx increment in .1's. e.g dx10.1 or dx11.2. There are also multiple versions of direct x 9 (9, 9b, 9c).